# Html constant character size

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am trying to create a web page using datatable where the description in the first column never wraps. This is a JSF-java application. I have tried to determine the maximum number of characters, and I have tried monospace font, without success.  How can this be achieved?

Note below that the number of dots (periods) and X's is the same, yet the X's wrap.

[image]

EDIT: here is the code from browser.  I also tried the "white-space:nowrap" suggestion which prevented the wrap but extended column1 width and I am hoping for a solution that allows the column widths to remain constant.  I apologize for any inappropriateness in this question, it is my first.

```css
html {
  font-size: 3vmax;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #005dff;
  /* font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; */
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="dtrows">
      <td class="dtcolumn1">
        <!-- column header -->
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Order No&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <!-- row record -->
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
      </td>
      <td class="dtcolumn2">
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Product Name&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <div class="noyes">
          <!--&lt;div class="no"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="no" style="width:; height:;"></div>
          <div class="mid"></div>
          <!--&lt;div class="yes"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="yes" style="width:; height:;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dtrows">
      <td class="dtcolumn1">
        <!-- column header -->
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Order No&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <!-- row record -->
        X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
      </td>
      <td class="dtcolumn2">
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Product Name&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <div class="noyes">
          <!--&lt;div class="no"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="no" style="width:; height:;"></div>
          <div class="mid"></div>
          <!--&lt;div class="yes"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="yes" style="width:; height:;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dtrows">
      <td class="dtcolumn1">
        <!-- column header -->
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Order No&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <!-- row record -->
        a
      </td>
      <td class="dtcolumn2">
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Product Name&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <div class="noyes">
          <!--&lt;div class="no"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="no" style="width:; height:;"></div>
          <div class="mid"></div>
          <!--&lt;div class="yes"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="yes" style="width:; height:;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dtrows">
      <td class="dtcolumn1">
        <!-- column header -->
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Order No&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <!-- row record -->
        b
      </td>
      <td class="dtcolumn2">
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Product Name&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <div class="noyes">
          <!--&lt;div class="no"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="no" style="width:; height:;"></div>
          <div class="mid"></div>
          <!--&lt;div class="yes"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="yes" style="width:; height:;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dtrows">
      <td class="dtcolumn1">
        <!-- column header -->
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Order No&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <!-- row record -->
        c
      </td>
      <td class="dtcolumn2">
        <!--&lt;f:facet name="header"&gt;Product Name&lt;/f:facet&gt;-->
        <div class="noyes">
          <!--&lt;div class="no"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="no" style="width:; height:;"></div>
          <div class="mid"></div>
          <!--&lt;div class="yes"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;-->
          <div class="yes" style="width:; height:;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Code should be in text, not images. And there are lots of css font styling thimgs like nowrap etc. This is a pure html/css thing.

Comment: From the screenshot, it's clear that your component didn't inherit the `font-family` property from the `html` element. Could you please show the HTML source of your component that comes to the browser, not the JSF source that generates it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the following CSS property on the element :

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

This will make sure the text will never wrap to the next line.